# how to raise a custom exception in main method proper?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, raiserror

I am trying to understand how to raise a custom error in main method with action. Below is my sudo code but don't work.

I want to raise a custom exception that will go to except in main method with tag, message value. but the below code output a class:

class '**main**.pdv_error_response'

```
class my_exceptions(Exception):
   """Base class for other exceptions"""
   pass

class pdv_error_response(my_exceptions):
    def __init__(self, tag, message):
        self.tag = tag
        self.tag = message

def tryerror(x):
    if x < 0:
        raise(pdv_error_response('test','output'))

def main():
    try:
        tryerror(-1)
    except:
        if pdv_error_response:
            print(pdv_error_response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are printing an object so it will not print your message for that you have to change in your `main()`.

```py
def main():
    try:
        tryerror(-1)
    except pdv_error_response as e:
        if pdv_error_response:
            print(e)
```

Now you can get your expected output.
You can refer [User Defined Exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) for more.